# Persistent realtime game authentication (JWT, Passport)

Tags: html5, html-canvas, websocket, realtime, authentication

**Context**

I am building a MMO game in HTML5 with canvas. 
I use **NodeJS** on server & **JS from scratch** on client.
I also use **socket.io** to manage realtime.
The game is persistent & each player keep their equipment / skills etc, even after logout.
To do that, the player need to register with email and password then login.
The client is a browser but could be other device like phone in future. I use **HTTPS** to encrypt communication.

**Problem**

In this context, I decide to use a token based authentication system. 
I look to JWT from Auth0 and found : https://jwt.io/introduction/

I noticed : They are talking about the JWS implementation of JWT and not about JWE. After looking at https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken I saw that it was the same thing, JWS and no JWE. I suppose that JWT module developed by Auth0 doesn't provide a JWE implementation of JWT but only a JWS implementation.

- **Am I right or did I miss something?** In my particular case (game scenario), I don't know if it's mandatory to encrypt with JWE (I don't think sensitive data will be passed in the token), do you think JWS enough?

In the side of this research, I checked for Passport (http://www.passportjs.org/docs/). I read the documentation but I didn't find information about how they perform authentication when we remove session (http://www.passportjs.org/docs/downloads/html/#disable-sessions).

I tried to implement it with `session: false` but no token was returned.

- **I supposed I need to implement it by myself, but in this case what's the goal of passport for a token based authentication?**

Then last question about socket.io

- If I implement a JWS token based authentication to signed my request & HTTPS to encrypt the communication, how can I secure the bidirectional communication? It looks like two different channel of communication, is it easy to implement that with socket.io?

Comment: I was going to create a short tutorial on how to do sessions with socket.io but realized you probably don't need one. Passport is there to make it super easy for you to implement logins far quicker than doing it yourself. However, if you're doing anything outside of their use cases, it's nigh impossible to edit. I had a similar issue with Passwordless so I read up on jwt.io and created my own system and it works pretty damn well. This answer helped me with getting user info via sessions https://stackoverflow.com/a/30937060/1167646